# laravel queue - release a job inside a queue batch/chain (API rate limits)

Tags: laravel, queue

I want to release a queue job back to the queue if example: I get response status from 3-third party API = 429. I saw I can do that to a queue job, but I need to release a job that's inside a **batch**. Searched the internet and didn't seem to find an answer if this is even possible.

Framework: Laravel > v.8

Here's an example for how I tried to solve it, but it didn't work. The release put the job back always in 5 sec., regardless of what I entered in `$this->release()`.

this is how I call the batch to start the process and when everything is finished successfully I need to proceed to another step of fetching data from the same API.

```
$jobs = $api->fetchJobsPlan($data);

Bus::batch($jobs)
    ->then(function () use ($property, $start_fetch_date) {
        static::step3($property, $start_fetch_date);
    })->catch(function ($e) {
        Log::error('Error in batch: '.$e);
    })
    ->onQueue('jobs')
    ->dispatch();
```

This is how I tried to execute the retry logic inside the queue job class:

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $data = $this->api->getDataInDay($this->start_date, $this->end_date);

        if ($data !== null && array_key_exists('retryAfter', $data)) {
            $time = Carbon::parse($data['retryAfter'][0]);
            $now = Carbon::now()->setTimezone($time->getTimezone());
            $retryAfterInSeconds = $time->diffInSeconds($now);
            // 600 = 10 minutes
            if ($retryAfterInSeconds > 600) {
                $retryAfterInSeconds = 600;
            }

            logger('release job in : '.$retryAfterInSeconds.' seconds');
            // Release the job back to the queue with a delay
            $this->release($retryAfterInSeconds);
            return;
        }
}
```